# tensorflow:Label inception has no images in the category training?

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, tensorflow, docker-compose

[image]

Input:`python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py --bottleneck_dir=/Potholes/bottleneck --how_many_training_steps 100 --model_dir=/Potholes/inception --output_graph=/Potholes/retrained_graph.pb --output_labels=/Potholes/retrained_labels.txt --image_dir /Potholes/Potholes/..`

Using docker for tensorflow and training the upper layer of Inception model and getting following error while retraining the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Mount The Drive Correctly in docker . 
   docker run -it - v $HOME/tf_files:/tf_files  (Tensorflow path)
2. make Two Folders inside your image folder .
3. if you want to make a Classifier than Put two folder for example if you want to make a Classifier of star wars poster than put one folder which contains pictures of star wars and other folder with images of other movies .
4. This would solve the error .